# JPA - Calling Oracle function without IN parameter

Tags: sql, spring, oracle, jpa

I'm trying to execute Oracle function which doesn't have any IN parameters:

```
FUNCTION SELECT_USER RETURN SYS_REFCURSOR IS
 refCurRetour SYS_REFCURSOR;
BEGIN
    OPEN refCurRetour FOR
    SELECT ID_RH, NOM, PRENOM, MAIL FROM ES_UTILISATEUR;
    RETURN refCurRetour;
         EXCEPTION
        WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
         NULL;
         WHEN OTHERS THEN
                RAISE;
END SELECT_USER;
```

I defined entity:

```
@Entity
@NamedNativeQuery(
        name = "selectUser",
        query = "{? = call SELECT_USER()}",
        resultClass = UserResult.class
)
public class UserResult {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "ID_RH")
    private String idrh;

    @Column(name = "NOM")
    private String nom;

    @Column(name = "PRENOM")
    private String prenom;

    @Column(name = "MAIL")
    private String mail;
}
```

and executed query:

```
    public List<UserResult> selectUser() {
        TypedQuery<UserResult> q = em.createNamedQuery("selectUser", UserResult.class);
        return q.getResultList();
    }
```

Problem is that I'm getting errors about undefined parameter:

```
java.sql.SQLException: Missing IN or OUT parameter at index :: 1
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Can you please show us the whole function ? Thanks!

Comment: Updated source code

Comment: Try to add `callable = true` to the `NamedNativeQuery`

Answer (score 0):

It seems I was using `@NamedNativeQuery` from `javax.persistence` package.

When I changed it to `org.hibernate.annotations` (+added `calleble = true`) problem was solved.